# A customizable diff tool that can produce report (in XML, HTML)

Tags: java, diff

I want to provide a diff report for a non regression test.
My program is Java based but I did not found any API filling my needs.

So I'm using an external tool (CSDiff) that take 2 files as arguments and return an HTML report.
That's nice and easy to setup.

Now the only problem I have is that the HTML report needs some tweaks to be used and I am messing around with the report, trying to transform it into something different (hidding some parts, changing the style, ...)

Does someone know a diff tools that has a powerful command line support, allowing custom report to be generated ? 
Nice report options would be 2 panes view, regexp filtering, easy styling options... something like the vim diff view in html would be great.

I've already read stuff about diff tools in stackoverflow but I don't find the stuff I'm looking for.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool
- [Free diff tool that is configurable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948164/free-diff-tool-that-is-configurable)
- [Need a Java and Javascript diff tool written in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954270/need-a-java-and-javascript-diff-tool-written-in-java)

Many Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend [google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/). This provides HTML or the basic diff components which you could style and transform yourself.

Comment: I've missed this one because of an aggressive proxy at work. I manage to get a copy of the source, and it's great ! 
Thanks a lot.
BTW, your answer need a little edit for formating purpose.

Answer (score 1):

[Pretty Diff](http://prettydiff.com/) provides an HTML report either on screen in a web browser or as HTML formatted text that can be saved as an HTML file.

Comment: Note: Pretty Diff is JavaScript, not Java.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know such library from top of my head but if Google search doesn't bring anything relevant back, I would take a look at Eclipse sources. Eclipse has very good text diff tool which you might be able to reuse, unless it's tied up pretty badly to their UI stuff, which I hope is not the case.

Comment: well, I was expecting a more easier way than a DIY using eclipse or whatever open source project (by the way I like the eclipse diff tool; I also like the one in FishEye.)